# Help me translate this calligraphy please!!! I would greatly appreciate it

Tags: translation, calligraphy

[image]
I recently got this artwork from an estate sale. However I don't see anyway of being able to translate it myself! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[《秋夕》 杜牧](http://www.tpomps.edu.hk/tpompschi/2006_2007/10/read.htm) - "Autumn Evening" by Du Mu

銀燭秋光冷畫屏，

輕羅小扇撲流螢。

天階夜色涼如水，

臥看牽牛織女星。

notes:

1. 銀燭(silver candle)： White candles, also known as "red candles"。
2. 秋光(Autumn light)： Autumn night's candlelight。
3. 冷畫屏(cold draw screen)： dim candlelight shines on the draw screen making its color hazy

畫屏(draw screen)：A screen with colored painting on it。

冷(cold)： used as a verb -- coldly shines。

4. 輕羅小扇(little fan made of light silk)

撲(wave at). The calligraphy here used 捕(capture), which differs from the original. It is more logical to use a fan to fan at the fireflies than use it to capture them, but 捕 could just be a symbolic way to express 'wave at'

5. 流螢：wandering fireflies
6. 天階：Open air stirs。

夜色涼如水 (night scene cool as water)

7. 臥看：lay down and watch。

牽牛織女星: [Altair and Vega](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiJ9ovvs-L-AhWUjIkEHS_eBpsQFnoECBEQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstar-name-registry.com%2Fblog%2Fitem%2Fthe-romance-of-altair-and-vega&usg=AOvVaw1WKZv_nNZDQXHcVkcCgZCB)

The smaller text describes the date, title, author, and location where this piece was written

杜牧 was a famous poet in the Tang dynasty

Comment: You're amazing, I love you, Thanks!!!

Comment: this is perfect answer, @Gavin can you accept it as the accepted answer so this thread marked as answered?

Answer (score 0):

> **The Double Seventh Night**
>
> *Du Mu*
>
> Autumn has chilled the painted screen in silver moonlight;
>
> A silken fan is used to catch flitting firefly.
>
> The steps seem steeped in water when cold grows the night.
>
> She lies to watch two stars in love meet in the sky.

This version is translated by **许渊冲** [(Wikipedia: 许渊冲)](https://zh.m.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E8%A8%B1%E6%B7%B5%E5%86%B2).

Answer (score 0):

杜牧《秋夕》
银烛秋光冷画屏，轻罗小扇扑流萤。
天街夜色凉如水，卧看牵牛织女星。